# Parse Android pushNotification with PhoneGap not work when app is closed?

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, phonegap-plugins, parse-platform

i successfully make send notification but the problem that notifications Only show when app is open or running in background , **i need to push notification and see it in status bar when app is totally closed ?????** .

i use this code in mainActivity

```
Parse.initialize(this, "", "");     
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
PushService.subscribe(this, "Broadcast", MainActivity.class);
```

and in AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

**i use phonegap cordova 2.5.0 with parse-1.2.3**

Answer (score 0):

Which Android permissions are you declaring in your Manifest? The [Push QuickStart](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart_push#android/native/existing) says that the following needs to be added to your Manifest as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permission in manifesto.xml
<> Blockquote

```
activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushWebview"/>
<activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageActivity"/>
<activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity"/

> Blockquote
```